# Cloning Anaconda environment to different machine

Tags: anaconda

I set an environment on my local machine and installed some packages (such as tensorflow etc.). I need to copy the environment (with all the packages I installed) and transfer it to another machine which is not connected to the internet.

Can anybody please help me with the cloning process? I copied the environment folder to the second machine but even when I'm activated the environment (this part worked) It does not recognise the environment Python version and the packages I installed.

For example, the "root" Python version is 3.7 and the environment Python version is 3.6.5. After I activated the environment the Python version was still 3.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to back up anaconda environment in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123749/how-to-back-up-anaconda-environment-in-windows-10)